# How do I delete an element that has an attribute using XmlDocument?

Tags: xml, vb.net

How do I delete an element that has an attribute?

I'm trying to delete:

```
  <User Name="1">
    <PrivateFtpAccountId-1>11111</PrivateFtpAccountId-1>
    <PrivatePassword-1>test1</PrivatePassword-1>
    <PublicFtpAccountId-1>22222</PublicFtpAccountId-1>
    <PublicPassword-1>test2</PublicPassword-1>
  </User>
```

from my xml that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Users>
  <User Name="1">
    <PrivateFtpAccountId-1>11111</PrivateFtpAccountId-1>
    <PrivatePassword-1>test1</PrivatePassword-1>
    <PublicFtpAccountId-1>22222</PublicFtpAccountId-1>
    <PublicPassword-1>test2</PublicPassword-1>
  </User>
  <User Name="2">
    <PrivateFtpAccountId-2>33333</PrivateFtpAccountId-2>
    <PrivatePassword-2>test3</PrivatePassword-2>
    <PublicFtpAccountId-2>44444</PublicFtpAccountId-2>
    <PublicPassword-2>test4</PublicPassword-2>
  </User>
</Users>
```

I get:

Unhandled Exception: System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: '/Users/User Name="1"' has
 an invalid token.

My console app code is:

```
    Dim nodes As XmlNodeList
    Dim myXmlDocument As New XmlDocument()
    Dim strUser As String
    Dim bSucess As Boolean = False

    strUser = "User Name=""1"""

    myXmlDocument.Load("MyGoodXMLfordeleting.xml")

    nodes = myXmlDocument.SelectNodes("/Users/" & strUser)

    For Each node As XmlNode In nodes
        If node IsNot Nothing Then
            node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node)
            myXmlDocument.Save("MyGoodXMLfordeleting.xml")
            bSucess = True
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath query is invalid.

Try an XPath query like:

```
/Users/User[@Name='1']
```

XPath samples here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx